# Parse JSON from .Net webservice on iPhone

Tags: ios, json

I call a webservice where I retreive a JSON from. Now the JSON is user defined, so can be different per user. The question is, how can I check in iOS what kind of value it is? (NSString, BOOL, NSNumber, NSDate etc.?)

Example JSON I receive (already into an NSArray):

```
<__NSArrayM 0x119d11040>(
0000000010,
SomeName,
1, <--- boolean
SomeText,
3133,
<null>,
<null>,
<null>,
<null>,
0,
/Date(1321536126810)/,
System\ABC,
<null>,
<null>
)
```

(This is a demo environment, so many values are `<null>`, but in production this can be strings, numbers, booleans, dates etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do some searching on the `isKindOfClass:` method.

Comment: Are you trying to map this into some static data model?

Comment: I can use the isKindOfClass method, but this works fine for NSString, but how about the .Net Date(... type and boolean etc.

Comment: What do you get for those other types? `NSNumber`? `NSDate`? Or perhaps `NSString` with special values you can look for?

Comment: For a boolean I get __NSCFBoolean, which I don't know how to use in isKindOfClass. For the date it just sees it as a NSString

Comment: There is no way in JSON to distinguish a date from a plain string or number.  There is no special date type.  In the above NSLog dump of an NSArray there is apparently an NSString that contains "/Date(1321536126810)/", but there's nothing to say that that's not simply a user's password.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the JSON syntax (it only takes 5 minutes and is well worth the time).  What you see is what you get.

Comment: (And note that JSON format is not "arbitrary" -- what elements appear where is defined by the particular web site, etc.  Ask the owner of the web site to tell you what the protocol is.)

Comment: Note that, if the original value was a Boolean, it should have been transmitted as "true" or "false" (without the quotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have received a JSON from server in valid format you can use `NSJSONSerialization` class to serialize it to some dictionary/array depending on the container type set in the JSON. The serialization process would not only generate a valid container (`NSArray`/`NSDictionary`) for you but it would also assign the contained values according to the types as in the JSON itself, for example, quoted values would be contained as `NSString`, numbers would be contained as `NSNumber`, null values would be contained as `NSNull` instance, etc. Below is a simple line of code that would convert a valid JSON to its equivalent Objective C container type, assuming `message` is a `NSString` representation of the JSON sent from server:

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:NULL];
```

However, in case of .NET web service, dates would come as string with prefix `/Date` and the serialization process would assume that as nothing but a `NSString`. So to find a date in your JSON you would have iterate through the parsed Objective-C array/dictionary(possibly using a `for in` loop) for a "/Date" prefix and then manually convert that to `NSDate`. This simple piece of code should do the trick for you:

```
if ([[str lowercaseString] hasPrefix:@"/date"]) { //str is a value in the parsed container with prefix /Date so assume that as date rather than a string
    NSTimeInterval interval = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[[[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/date(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")/" withString:@""] longLongValue]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        NSDate* dt = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:interval];
       //do whatever with dt now
}
```

Finally, for .NET datatypes, .NET `null` is parsed as `[NSNull null]` not `nil` what one might expect. So you should assume a `nil` when you have found a `[NSNull null]` in your container while iterating. Also, the .NET `bool` data type would be parsed to 0/1 and that is only a `NSNumber` that in turn can be converted to `int`, `float`, `BOOL` or any other valid Objective C number format but there is no way one can determine if it was originally a .NET `bool` unless he/she knows the structure and datatypes of the JSON, in advance.

Comment: Thanks.. That was what I was afraid of ;-)

Comment: @CyberK In that case you are out of luck :(

Comment: Actually, a reasonably good serializer would translate Boolean values into the true/false keywords.  (Of course, getting them back is a trick.)

Comment: @HotLicks actually you are right. true/false are valid in JSON formats. However even if a good serializer serializes a bool to true/false, the Objective C deserializer can at most parse them down to a `NSNumber` and not to a `BOOL` as `BOOL` is not of pointer type and the developer would struggle with the same end result! I guess this is a design flaw of Objective C by itself and not of any JSON serializer :(

Comment: @AyanSengupta - Yep, pretty much all of the languages that implement JSON parsers have some sort of shortcoming.  In Objective-C it's at least possible to tell that the value *might be* a bool, but it's impossible to be sure (without separately scanning the JSON source string).

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the `[object class];` by doing the following: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(object.class));`

If you are looking into parsing the JSON, try using `NSJSONSerialization`. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Actually, you can just NSLog object.class.  That will invoke `description` on the class, printing it's name.

Comment: But you don't need to use NSStringFromClass.

Comment: ah! thats what you meant :) Thats just a personal preference of mine... always trust apple's code.

Answer (score 0):

For the Date, I have a Utilities class that has some easy methods for dealing with SQL dates from .NET.  Here is one that makes an NSDate object from the date coming in JSON:

```
+ (NSDate *)nsDateFromDotNetJSONString:(id)object {

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
        return (NSDate *)object;
    }

    if (![object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSString *string = (NSString *)object;

    static NSRegularExpression *dateRegEx = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        dateRegEx = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"^\\/date\\((-?\\d++)(?:([+-])(\\d{2})(\\d{2}))?\\)\\/$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
    });
    NSTextCheckingResult *regexResult = [dateRegEx firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (regexResult) {
        // milliseconds
        NSTimeInterval seconds = [[string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:1]] doubleValue] / 1000.0;
        // timezone offset
        if ([regexResult rangeAtIndex:2].location != NSNotFound) {
            NSString *sign = [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:2]];
            // hours
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:3]]] doubleValue] * 60.0 * 60.0;
            // minutes
            seconds += [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", sign, [string substringWithRange:[regexResult rangeAtIndex:4]]] doubleValue] * 60.0;
        }

        return [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here is one I use to take an NSDate and format for SQL:

```
+(NSString *)sqlDateStringFromNSDate:(NSDate *)date {
    if (date == nil) {
        return @"";
    }

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: With regard to dates and servers you also need to be careful of users that have their clock set to 12 hour and not 24 hour http://www.flexicoder.com/blog/index.php/2013/10/ios-24-hour-date-format/

Comment: @Hot Licks - what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, why are you testing for an NSDate in the second line of your code when there would never be an NSDate in deserialized JSON?

Comment: Just in case someone does something stupid and passes in an NSDate.

Comment: Why not a diagnostic message??

Comment: And if you're going to format the time without AM/PM, shouldn't you use a 24-hour format??

Comment: @HotLicks it should be HH:mm:ss obviously.